# Char type on 32 bit vs 64 bit

Tags: c++

Here is the following issue:

If I am developing on a 32 bit machine and want my code to be ported to a 64 bit machine here is the senario.

My function internally use a lot of `std` strings. Now if I want to provide APIs can I ask them to send `char *` which I can then use internally? Or ask them to send me a `__int64` which I convert to a string?

Another reason to use `char *` in my API was that at least in one type of implementation of unix (a different version of the tool) it picks up data from `stdin` via `argv` which is a `char *`.

In the Windows version I am not sure what to do. I could just ask for `__int64` and then convert it into a string...and make it work that way or just use `char *` as well?

Comment: I do not understand the problem you are having. Char is char everywhere. What does `__int64` have to do with `char*`? Why would you want to convert between the two on 64 bit target and not on 32 bit one?

Comment: i don't have to do anything I am the one providing the API. however, i was curious. so if i give them something like void printcode(const char * input, char * output_code) as opposed to void printcode(const __int64, char * output_code) will that be a problem since my static lib is created on a 32 bit os? can they run it correctly on a 64 bit os? and not have any issues? never done this before so just trying to clarify?

Comment: Note a 64 bit application can not load a 32 bit library anyway.  They will either have to develop their app as a 32 bit app(which will run fine on a 64 bit system), or they will have to recompile your library to make it 64 bit.

Comment: they won't have access to recompiling the lib that is restricted. so i guess that means they will have to build a 32 bit app on a 64bit box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem somewhat confused. If the code you are writing is used only within the target machine, recompile will take care of most of the problems. Just don't rely on specific memory layout and you are fine. Using strings (as opposed to wstrings) probably means that the character encoding is UTF-8 (if not, reconsider) and thus limited form of data exhance (e.g. files) between platforms is also fine.

In this case, your interface decision comes to selecting between `(const) std::string(&)`, and `(const) char*, integer_type` (don't rely on null terminator, please). Deciding factor being whether or not you anticipate need to support other compilers or programming languages.

Now, if you intent to make the interface callable from other machines (i.e. network interface), you have much tougher job. In that case, specify size of everything explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

If you're providing a C++ implementation, then your public interface should just use `std::string`.

If however for compatibility reasons (which it sounds like you may have) you need to provide a C-style interface, then using `char*` is precisely the way to do it. In your 32-bit library it will be a 32 bit pointer, and in the 64 bit version of the library it will be 64 bits. This will then agree with the client users' expectations regarding the API. You should absolutely convert to a `std::string` inside your library at the earliest possible point however.

Comment: Using `std::string` in the interface isn't very smart. `const char*` is both-way compatible with `std::string` and still allows the usage of plain C-strings.

Comment: Looks like he wants to port a 32-bit binary if he is talking about a library.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: and what is the advantage of c-strings in a C++ program?

Comment: yes i am trying to port my lib to a "potential" 64 bit box although it could run on a 32bit as well.

Answer (score 0):

You would do well to convert to string at the earliest opportunity, it is the recommended/standard for C++, and will help do away with all your char* problems.

There is a few scenarios you can follow to write portable code, see these questions:
[What's the funniest user request you've ever had?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/718582/15161)
[How to do portable 64 bit arithmetic, without compiler warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4017621/15161)

You would have problems achieving binary portability between different architectures, C++ provides for source-level portability.

Comment: i was just wondering that since i made this static lib in a 32 bit os would providing an api in  char * format be a problem? so eg. void test(const char * input) or void test (__int64 input); the former is easier the latter i would need to convert to a string and go about my business. the question is that is the char * form bad? will it have compatibility issues?

Comment: char* is bad in the sense that it limits you to c-type strings, std::string has a built-in function c_str() to retrieve c-type strings if you really need them. Also if you use <limits>-include-file you can determine the sizes of the types at run-time.

Comment: the only reason i used char * was so that i don't have compatibility issues. i do use strings internally the only one fear is that the char * that holds the hexadecimal value is not going to be messed up since my static lib is compiled on a 32 bit box and they are using it on a 64 bit box.

Answer (score 0):

`char` is always one byte in size, both on 32-bit and 64-bit systems. However, using the `std` library is not the worst choice. ;) `std` should cope with different platforms as it is platform independent for the "most" part...

Comment: Just note that one byte doesn't mean 8bits.

Comment: well do i need to be afraid of big/little indian issues then? i mean would i be taking all of that for  granted?

Comment: @user245823 No you don't have to be afraid of little/big endian issues. Char will still work as a char, and a sequence of chars will still work as a continuous string. Of course that assumes you are talking about conversions into text representation, not 1:1 memory copy.

Comment: internally i am use byte arrays so i am not too worried about those. but its just a matter of getting the initial input value which at the moment is coming in as a char * rather than __int64. so that is the only issue at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Converting to/from `char*` doesn't really help if you can't represent the number on your architecture.

If you are converting a 64bit integer from its decimal (or hexadecimal) textual representation into a value, you still need 64bits to store it.